# Sodium Crypto box seal open not working in PHP

Tags: php, public-key-encryption, libsodium

So I'm trying to get libsodium's [`sodium_crypto_box_seal`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sodium-crypto-box-seal.php) and [`sodium_crypto_box_seal_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sodium-crypto-box-seal-open.php) working but for some reason, the open is failing and I can't work out why.

So in all my trying to get this working, I have built a test system that a single PHP file that tests how it would work cross server.

```
<pre>
<?php
/*** Client Sending ***/
// saved argument
$remotePublic = "DXOCV4BU6ptxt2IwKZaP23S4CjLESfLE+ng1tMS3tg4=";

// create out key for this message
$key = sodium_crypto_box_keypair();

// encrypt our message using the remotePublic
$sealed = sodium_crypto_box_seal("This is a test", base64_decode($remotePublic));
$send = json_encode((object)array("pub" => base64_encode(sodium_crypto_box_publickey($key)), "msg" => base64_encode($sealed)));
echo "Sending : {$send} \r\n";

/*** Server Setup ***/
$payload = json_decode($send);
$apps = 
array (
  'test' => 
  array (
    'S' => 'lv/dT3YC+Am1MCllkHeA2r3D25HW0zPjRrqzR8sepv4=',
    'P' => 'DXOCV4BU6ptxt2IwKZaP23S4CjLESfLE+ng1tMS3tg4=',
  ),
);

/*** Server Opening ***/
$msg = $payload->msg;
$key = sodium_crypto_box_keypair_from_secretkey_and_publickey(base64_decode($apps['test']['S']), base64_decode($apps['test']['P']));
$opened = sodium_crypto_box_seal_open(base64_decode($msg), $key);
echo "Opened : {$opened} \r\n";

/*** Server Responding ***/
$sealedResp = base64_encode(sodium_crypto_box_seal("We Got your message '{$opened}'", base64_decode($payload->pub)));
echo "Responding : {$sealedResp}\r\n";

/*** Client Receiving ***/
$received = sodium_crypto_box_seal_open(base64_decode($sealedResp), $key);
echo "Received : {$received}\r\n";

/*** Sanity Checking ***/
if($received == "We Got your message 'This is a test'"){
    echo "Test Successfull.\r\n";
}else{
    echo "Test Failed got '{$received}' is not \"We Got your message 'This is a test'\"\r\n";
}
?>
</pre>
```

Output is:

```
Sending : {"pub":"DS2uolF5lXZ1E3rw0V2WHELAKj6+vRKnxGPQFlhTEFU=","msg":"VVYfphc2RnQL2E8A0oOdc6E\/+iUgWO1rPd3rfodjLhE+slEWsivB6QiaLiMuQ31XMP\/1\/s+t+CSHu8QukoY="} 
Opened : This is a test 
Responding : cvDN9aT9Xj7DPRhYZFGOR4auFnAcI3qlwVBBRY4mN28JmagaR8ZR9gt6W5C0xyt06AdrQR+sZFcyb500rx6iDTEC4n/H77cUM81vy2WfV8m5iRgp
Received : 
Test Failed got '' is not "We Got your message 'This is a test'"
```

Comment: Check the return value of `sodium_crypto_box_seal` and friends: they can return `false` on failure. Also, check your logs (turning up your log_level if needed). That'll at least narrow down where it starts to go off the rails.

Comment: Error logging is set to E_ALL and display_errors is set to true so I would see if there are errors, also if it's false I would not see any data in the base64 encoded output. the base64 of `` is still ``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two problems here.

First -- in this step under "Server Opening":

```
$opened = sodium_crypto_box_seal_open($msg, $key);
```

`$msg` is still Base64 encoded, so trying to decrypt it will fail.

Second -- the public key that is included in the `"pub"` field of `$send` is the public key of a random keypair that was generated by `sodium_crypto_box_keypair()`, **not** the same public key as `$remotePublic` or the pair in `$apps`. This key is overwritten by a call to `sodium_crypto_box_keypair_from_secretkey_and_publickey()` later in the application, making the original message unrecoverable.

Comment: To your second yeah the public key is a random generation for every response from the servers. But that fixed the client to the server but not the server to the client

Comment: What do you expect that to accomplish? If you generate a new keypair for every response and throw it away, you won't be able to read any messages encrypted to those keys.

Comment: Receiving is parsed in the same execution as the Sending, so it Goes Send Wait Receive

Comment: Ah found it so it's because it's all in one script I'm overwriting `$key`